# if conditional in bash giving error

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script where I want to get the format of a file.

```
FILENAME=$1

GET_FILE_FORMAT=`file $FILENAME | grep -i data`
if[[ "$GET_FILE_FORMAT" = *data* ]]
        echo "Format Data";
fi
```

However the output that I get is as follows

```
./try.bash test.data
./try.bash: line 4: if[[ test.data : data = *data* ]]: No such file or directory
Format Data
./try.bash: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./try.bash: line 6: `fi'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You don't have any space after `if`.
2. The end of the conditional, i.e. `if`, isn't indicated.

To fix, say:

```
if [[ "$GET_FILE_FORMAT" = *data* ]]; then
```

To prevent getting incorrect information when the *file name* itself contains the string `data`, say:

```
GET_FILE_FORMAT=$(file "${FILENAME}" | awk -F: '{print $NF}')
```

Comment: But then you don't need to capture the output in a variable and test it again in the shell. `if file "$FILENAME" | awk -F: '$NF ~ /data/ { exit 0 } END { exit 1 }'; then ...` or better yet just `case $(file "$FILENAME") in *:data ) ... ;; esac`

Comment: @tripleee Maybe, even more succinctly, `[[ $(file "$1" | awk -F: '{print $NF}') = *data* ]] && echo "Format data"`